# k8s + wireguard - cannot use port-forward in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I cannot run `port-forward` in my k8s environment (based on k3s) and it shows **failed to execute portforward in network namespace "...": failed to dial 8080: dial tcp4: lookup localhost: no such host** error message when send the request to localhost:8080 (8080 is the exposed port of the `k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4`) .

The environment is:

1. The wireguard server with public IP (10.0.0.0/16)
2. The k3s server behind in NAT, connect to wireguard (10.0.1.2/32 and allowIP 10.0.0.0/24)
3. The pod IP in k3s are (10.42.0.0/16)

Based in this environment I got the error message when I enable the wireguard in k3s host server + run port-forward command. But it success when disable the wireguard client. How can I solve this issue?

PS. `kubectl proxy` works smoothly.

[UPDATE 09-27]

More detail about my environment

1. Server A in internet with WireGuard server (**10.0.0.0/16**)
2. My Laptop with WireGuard (**10.0.1.1/32**)
3. Server B behind NAT and Connect to WireGuard (**10.0.1.2/32**)

The Server B also install the k3s by default setting and deploy POD (k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4) as the demo pod. The IP is **10.42.0.9** get by command `kubectl describe pod`

When I run `kubectl port-forward PODNAME 8080:8080 -v=4` in my laptop and run `sudo k3s kubectl port-forward PODNAME 8080:8080` in Server B, I get the same error message

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8080
Handling connection for 8080
E0927 23:17:59.251557  140082 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 8080 -> 8080: error forwarding port 8080 to pod cbb517f914c88a3e063eb5982c182bc51fdc52a3d80acaf2c93876b0edba8d77, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-719289c5-7d83-02a9-3679-638ba1cc50bb": failed to dial 8080: dial tcp4: lookup localhost: no such host
```

And as I mentioned before, when I disconnect WireGuard in Server B everything goes smoothly and without any proble.

PS. I setup the kubernates environment via just run `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -` and the host server is ArchLinux.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? Can you provide your configuration? Please also share your logs.

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor sorry for late response since I'm busy in resign last week

Comment: PS. I both check localhost:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8080 and get the same error message

Comment: Did you see [this issue](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/484)? Is it similar to yours?

Comment: Still cannot find the reason, but after re-install the ArchLinux (k3s server) the problem solved ...

Comment: I've solved this problem by re-install my host environment (ArchLinux)
everything go smoothly with unknown reason ...